What is the best scalable way to implement a ContextProvider to fetch and filter data
I have been working on a project that requires fetching a bunch of data and provides multiple ways to filter/search the data, and I though about keeping filtering on the server-side considering I'll be using pagination.
I started using React Context recently and tried an approach that didn't work.
here's the custom React hook I'm using to fetch data
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const useFetch = (url, url_params) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState(null);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    const [refresh, setRefresh] = useState(0);

    if (url_params) {
        url = url + '?' + url_params.toString();
    }

    const refreshData = () => {
        setRefresh((prev) => prev + 1);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await fetch(url);
                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
                }
                const result = await response.json();
                setData(result);
            } catch (error) {
                setError(error);
            } finally {
                setLoading(false);
            }
        };

        fetchData();
    }, [refresh, url]);

    return { data, loading, error, refreshData };
};

export default useFetch;

and here is the contextProvider:
import { createContext, useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import { listing_url } from "../../Hooks/api_endpoints";
import useFetch from "../../Hooks/useFetch";
import { useSearchParams } from "react-router-dom";

export const HouseContext = createContext();

export const HouseProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [selectedHouse, setSelectedHouse] = useState(null);
    // I have tried multiple approaches for searchParams (one is search params and the other is testParams
    const [searchParams, setSearchparams] = useState({
        address__icontains: '',
        apartment_no__icontains: '',
        block__iexact: '',
        currency__iexact: '',
        floor__iexact: '',
        gross__gte: '',
        gross__lte: '',
        net__gte: '',
        net__lte: '',
        num_of_floors__iexact: '',
        num_of_rooms__iexact: '',
        owner__icontains: '',
        owner_phone_num__icontains: '',
        price__gte: '',
        price__lte: '',
        status__iexact: '',
        view__icontains: '',
    });

    // second attempt at implementing searchParams
    const testParams = new URLSearchParams({
        address__icontains: '',
        apartment_no__icontains: '',
        block__iexact: '',
        currency__iexact: '',
        floor__iexact: '',
        gross__gte: '',
        gross__lte: '',
        net__gte: '',
        net__lte: '',
        num_of_floors__iexact: '',
        num_of_rooms__iexact: '',
        owner__icontains: '',
        owner_phone_num__icontains: '',
        price__gte: '',
        price__lte: '',
        status__iexact: '',
        view__icontains: '',
    });

    const { data: houses, error: housesError, loading: housesLoading, refreshData: houseRefresh } = useFetch(listing_url, testParams);

    const createHouse = async (house) => {

        const newHouse = await fetch(listing_url, {
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify(houseData),
        });
        setHouses([...houses, newHouse]);
    }

    // useEffect(() => {
    //     console.log("houses were updated")
    //     console.log(' search params were updated')
    // }, [houses, testParams])

    const updateSearchParams = (key, value) => {
        console.log("firing updateSearchParams")
        houseRefresh();
        testParams.set(key, value);
    }

    return (
        <HouseContext.Provider value={{ houses, selectedHouse, housesError, housesLoading, setSelectedHouse, createHouse, testParams, updateSearchParams }}>
            {children}
        </HouseContext.Provider>
    )
}


and here's how I tried to use the filtering options in my Homepage:
import { HouseContext } from '../../Context/House/House';

// .....

export default function Home() {
// .....

    const { testParams, updateSearchParams } = useContext(HouseContext)

    // ......
    return (
          // ......

          <div className='flex'>
            <span className='text-sm/3 my-auto pr-2 dark:text-white'>floor</span>
            <input type='number' placeholder='floor' min={0} onChange={(e) => { updateSearchParams('floor__iexact', e.target.value) }} className='w-14 rounded border border-black' />
          </div>
    // .....

now I have 2 questions about this:

why is the houses list not getting updated when updateSearchParams is firing?
is this approach valid or should I just resort to fetching the data and then filtering client-side? and if so, how will I do so once pagination is added?


Do you know where within the chain the updateSearchParams is failing? Is the fetch never fired again? Or are we not updating the testParams correctly? or is it something else

@justnut to my knowledge testParams is updating and useFetch inside the contextProvider is getting called again, but the houses list is not getting updated

Where is the function 'setHouses' used within createHouse coming from?

@justnut oh my bad that was from the previous itteration

I believe the issue you are running into here is caused by nothing triggering a re-render, hence you are not seeing any changes with houses.
The easiest way to fix this I believe is the following:
const [testParams, setTestParams] = useState(new URLSearchParams({ ... rest of the tings })

Then update updateSearchParams to do the following instead of the testParams setting you were doing:
setTestParams(prev => {
    const newParam = new URLSearchParams(prev);
    newParam.set(key, value);
    return newParam;
});

This changing should now cause React to trigger a re-render and hopefully show you the updated houses.
I would also be careful with the onChange you are currently doing, this can cause some issues and a lot of requests being sent.
